# IN your previous module vs ON your previous module

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to use the preposition ON when referring to a **printed** module or text?

Here's the complete sentence:

> On your previous module, you learned about the basics of Algebra.

I feel like IN is more appropriate here. I just can't point out exactly why.

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about a module as a whole entity and referring to the contents of the module, 'in' is more natural. Whatever it is you focus on is contained within the module. It is inside the general thing we call 'module'.

> In a previous module, you learned about algebra. In this module, we will study calculus.

When referring to some kind of printed text (a physical object) you generally use 'on' to refer to specific areas (the text is on the surface of the paper).

> Please look at Exercise 4 on the module printout.
> There is a diagram on the second page of the handout.

The difference is that 'in the module' is referring to it as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

In your previous module= right.

Let's **focus on** this module.= right.

For any kind of text, we say in, never on. In book, in an article,etc.

[not the basics of algebra. basic algebra. And learn about: just learn]

Comment: What's wrong with "Basics of Algebra"? Also, past tense is essential, isn't it? Previous module is already taught, then how come "learn" instead of "learned/learnt"?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh One learns basic algebra and not about the basics of algebra/ To learn about something sounds like TV news or gossip. I learned about x when my neighbour told me. And I fail to see how one could learn the basics of algebra....